# POST handling success message to user file download

Tags: php, post, download, alert

To share files with friends, I have a simple system in which one can input a password, that password is sent via POST to self (`action=""`) and the password is checked against a database. If correct, the corresponding file will be downloaded with:

```
header('Content-Type: application/zip');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename="'.$filename.'"');
header('Content-Length: '.filesize($filename) );
readfile($filename);
```

Now, I have some error alerts (Bootstrap) when a password is e.g. incorrect (then the file download is skipped, of course). But I want to display an alert when the password is correct, as well.

But when I try to add html with php when I also change the header and read the file, nothing shows up.

Any suggestions on how to fix this? Thanks!

Comment: You could probably do this an easier way via htaccess/htpasswd.

Comment: What part could be easier?

Comment: You don't have to do anything. User inputs password if correct file is served to the user as mime-type dictates. If not an html page is loaded saying access denied.

Comment: Yeah but that wasn't my issue, moreover I want a good looking interface and not relying on htpasswd, and having the option for multiple files in the server to share.

Answer (score 0):

(Sorry, I don't have 50 reputation so I have to post an answer)

Did you try to redirect to an other page with JavaScript?
On this page you can put your alert

Comment: I like to keep the user on the same page, to avoid confusion, and keep the use simple.

Answer (score 0):

A response to an HTTP request is a single response. There's just one response to each HTTP request.

The response can either be an HTML page, containing your alert message, or a download, in the manner you're already doing.

The typical approach that's used to implement this kind of functionality is return an HTML response, containing the message; and with a refresh directive in the `<head>` element, that causes the browser to issue a 2nd request, which results in the download.

Comment: With HTTP meta refresh I can go to another page, but how do I download the file like with `readfile`? Do I need another page that then executes the download code in my Question?

Comment: On the web server's side, you're not downloading anything. You're sending the contents of the file as a response to the web browser's request. It's the web browser that downloads the file. Your response to an HTTP POST consists of an HTML message with an alert message, and a meta refresh. Your response to the meta refresh is the file to be downloaded by the browser, using the code you've already posted.